# ModuleNotFoundError even though module/file clearly exists

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I keep getting the error below after trying many different ways of importing files in Python.

```
  File "/Users/mengjial/Documents/Python_Programs/flask-rethink/flask-rethink/app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
import forms

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forms'
```

The structure of the `/Users/mengjial/Documents/Python_Programs/flask-rethink/flask-rethink/app/` folder is as below

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── forms.cpython-39.pyc
│   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
├── forms.py
├── models.py
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   └── index.html
└── views.py
```

Clearly `forms.py` is parallel to `views.py` in the same directory, and in `views.py` I have

```
import sys
sys.path.append('f/Users/mengjial/Documents/Python_Programs/flask-rethink/flask-rethink/app/forms.py')
import forms
```

What went wrong for me?

Comment: there is an in-depth conversation worth reading if you want to understand how imports work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: Thanks for pasting the link here!! @TaylorCochran

Answer (score 3):

In this case, maybe this should work:

```py
from . import forms
```

I tried it, and worked fine.